# SQL UNION, check if result is first or second query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query like :

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table WHERE "_CONDITIONS" 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM database2.table WHERE "_CONDITIONS"
```

With this query, I retrieve datas from `table` in `database1` and `database2`. `Table` is exactly the same for each database.

I put the result into a php variable (big array), but how can I know if a result is from `database1` or `database2` ? How can i add something in SQL for do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `union`, unless you want to remove duplicates. Use `union all`.  And then just add a column:

```
SELECT t.*, 1 as which FROM database1.table t WHERE "_CONDITIONS"
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*, 2 as which FROM database2.table t WHERE "_CONDITIONS";
```